# Is it possible to view a BIM model using ArcGIS Web without using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Lets say that I have a Revit file and I want to view it in the map. I currently do it using ArcGIS Pro by:

- Opening the file in ArcGIS Pro.
- Publishing it as a Web Scene
- Opening the published web scene using ArcGIS Javascript API.

**My aim is to not use ArcGIS Pro but do it directly. I have the file and I will upload the file and the viewer gives me the BIM Model placed in the map. Is this possible using any of the API's?**

Answer (score 3):

At this current point in time, there exists no workflow to import Revit models directly into ArcGIS Online/Enterprise.

Here is a recent blog article by Esri Canada explaining the different steps to publish a Revit model as a BuildingSceneLayer: 
https://resources.esri.ca/education-and-research/student-project-highlights-best-practices-in-bim-workflows

It requires the following steps in ArcGIS Pro:

- Import Revit (.rvt) file
- Georeference model
- [Convert to Geodatabase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/bimfile-to-geodatabase.htm)
- Publish as BuildingSceneLayer

Additional resources:

- [ArcGIS Pro documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/revit/adding-revit-data-to-arcgis-pro.htm)
- [BuildingSceneLayer documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-BuildingSceneLayer.html) using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Comment: My aim is to not use ArcGIS Pro but only the web tools.

Comment: Hi Georgy, I hear you and while it's likely to be possible in the future, at this point there is no way around ArcGIS Pro.